# Rails validating uniqueness of polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following:

```
class Membership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :member, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :group, polymorphic: true
end
```

As you can see my Membership model is doubly polymorphic. I want to validate the uniqueness of `:member` scoped by `:group`.

I was hoping the following would work:

```
validates :member, uniqueness: { scope: :group }
```

But this causes an error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Membership::Member
```

Is there a Rails way of doing this, or do I need to write a custom method for it?

Comment: I just have tried this code in Rails 5.0 and received the same error. Also I tried in Rails 5.1 and the code works fine, no errors.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no built-in for this, so I did the following:

```
validate :member_is_unique_for_group

def member_is_unique_for_group
  if group.members.include? member
    errors.add(:member, 'already exists for this group')
  end
end
```

Comment: This prevents me from updating the record. Did you also experience it?  

Adding `validate :member_is_unique_for_group, on: :create` worked

Comment: This approach creates a race condition, see the end of this paragraph: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#scopes-for-has-many-distinct

> Note that checking for uniqueness using something like include? is subject to race conditions. Do not attempt to use include? to enforce distinctness in an association.

Answer (score 2):

```
validates :member_id, :uniqueness => { :scope => [:member_type, :group_id,:group_type] }
```

With this, you might also want to make presence of member and group both mandatory, as nil values will lead to duplicates and will fail the uniqueness validation

```
validates :member_type, :member_id, :presence => true
validates :group_type, :group_id, :presence => true
```

Comment: Thanks this won't do it though because like I said, my model is doubly polymorphic. meaning each member id identified by member_type (which can be User, Organisation, Network) and member_id..... So I wrote my own custom method, see my answer. Cheers anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I used rohan's answer but added another validation for `group_id`

```
validates :group_id, uniqueness: { :scope => [:group_type, : member_id,: member_type] }
validates :member_id, uniqueness: { :scope => [:member_type, : group_id,: group_type] }
```

I also added a DB index

```
add_index :memberships, [:group_id, :group_type, :member_id, :member_type], unique: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this. (`on: :create` allows updating)

```
validate :group_member_uniqueness, on: :create
def group_member_uniqueness
  if Membership.where(group: group, member: member).exists?
    errors[:base] << 'That has already been added'
  end
end
```

DB index

`add_index :memberships, [:group_id, :group_type, :member_id, :member_type], unique: true`